# How to run Django API on my local machine with OAuth tokens

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have downloaded the Django REST Framework project from Github. Now I want to test the API on my local machine, but it uses OAuth Authentication.

I am running the API on localhost. Now I want to use Postman for testing purposes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.